# Get size video and duration on React native Expo WEB

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a problem im trying to upload videos with Expo ImagePicker. In ios and android it’s working but on WEB no!, I can’t get the same assets.
On ios and android i have this assets:

```
 "assets": [
    {
      "assetId": "C166F9F5-B5FE-4501-9531",
      "base64": null,
      "duration": null,
      "exif": null,
      "fileName": "IMG.HEIC",
      "fileSize": 6018901,
      "height": 3025,
      "type": "image",
      "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/cropped1814158652.jpg"
      "width": 3024
    }
```

But on Web only this:

- uri: 'data:(image or video) ;base64,' + asset.base64
- height and width.

So I don't know to get the duration of the video and the size of the file to limit.
So thats my problem on Web.
Any suggestions? That would helpme a lot…

```js
const onVideo = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,      
      allowsEditing: true,      
      quality: 1,        
         
    },);
    if (!result.canceled && result.assets && result.assets.length > 0) {
      
      if (result.assets.length === 1) {        
        try {
          setVideo(result.assets[0]);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }        
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: get ffmpeg and use web assessmbly then use ffmpeg-probe to get the duration of said video on web.